Replacing light bulb in flat fixture
I just purchased a new home and am in the repair process and one or two of the light fixtures appear to require bulb replacements. I was able to twist the main cover off of the fixture but underneath that is a plastic covering that I cant seem to open.
Has anyone encountered one of these before?


Have a feeling you replace the whole fixture.  Have you tried moving the red button yet?  See if that helps first.

the metal hook indicates to me that the release mechanism is on the other side, but I agree with the answer, it's a very likely non-replaceable bulb

It's possible that if you pry the hook down and towards the middle of the panel, it will release from the bar—the notch in the back of the case may be to allow that movement.  If not, it's likely a hinge point and as suggested, the latch is actually diametrically opposite.

there is no light bulb in that fixture ... the light comes from a multitude of LED chips

It might be the switch...

If there are multiple light fixtures that don't work, it could be a breaker that has tripped.

Does it have a maker's name or part number visible on the casing? You could probably find the installation leaflet online, and work it backwards. I suspect that at the far end of the metal supporting bracket you will find a narrow slot, and pushing an insulated screwdriver into that will release a clip, so the whole thing will hinge down for access, leaving the thin base screwed to the ceiling. MAKE SURE the power is off, and test everything you can reach with a non-contact AC detector and neon screwdriver as well. These are often emergency lighting with a separate power supply.

That's an LED fixture without a replaceable bulb. The form-factor and color-temperature switch are both indicators of that.
You might be able to get a new driver (most likely part it actually would need - converts AC house supply to DC for the LEDs) or you replace the whole fixture.

I have no idea why anyone would buy one of these.   They don't last 10-20 years.   A friend bought a bunch for townhouses he rents.   He is now replacing them a few years later vs. the tenants putting in a new bulb.   Wow what a massive waste of time and money.

I bought a couple of these for my home last year because I like the aesthetic and the form factor fit the space well. If I do end up having to replace them in a few years, it won't take a lot of time.
